# Tint Adjustment Mode crash

Tags: ios

I keep getting the following crash in my app:

```
-[UIView tintAdjustmentMode]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x17036ab00
```

It seems to only occur after loading a modal view controller (using iOS 7's custom animatable transition controllers) with a map in the modal view.

Has anyone seen this crash? I'm not using `tintAdjustmentMode` anywhere in the app.

Comment: Please show a piece of code. Crash suggests that you call `tintAdjustmentMode` method on `UIView` instance which has been deallocated a moment ago. More code you show, better answer you get.

Comment: The issue is that I'm not calling tintAdjustmentMode anywhere in the app, so it must be iOS that's doing this on its own. So I'm not really sure what code I should be posting...

Comment: Ok, so maybe add exception breakpoint and maybe you get some more info about this crash. Somewhere view is deallocated but should not be deallocated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that I needed to set MKMapView's delegate to `nil` in `viewWillDisappear`.